# How to use "while" in the middle of the sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

I am confused.  Is using *while* correct in the following sentence:

> Most students are able to expertly manage their time *while* they work
>   along with their other responsibilities.

Is it correct to use *while* or I should change the whole sentence?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I would probably say *whilst* in this instance, but that may be because I am British. I would also add a little punctuation *Most students are able expertly to manage their time, whilst they work, along with their other responsibilities*.

Comment: @WS2 - Using *whilst* in the US would get you some strange looks.

Comment: @HotLicks Your point being?

Comment: @WS2 - *Whilst* is not idiomatic in the US.

Comment: @HotLicks It's not idiomatic in Timbuktu either. So what?

Comment: @WS2 - Just sayin'.

Comment: @WS2 - I personally hate the word 'whilst' and would always prefer 'while.' Whilst just sounds pretentious, even in the UK. Much like people who use 'utilise' instead of 'use.' That's just personal opinion though.

Comment: @Jascol If it was good enough for Shakespeare it is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use of while is fine in the middle of a sentence like this. The use will be in the following way: *Most students are able expertly to manage their time **while working**, along with their other responsibilities.*

Comment: I work along with my coworkers, not along with my other responsibilities. I think there's a missing comma before "along" in the original which you dropped before you rewrote the sentence.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The comma will shift from before "while".

Answer (score -2):

Your usage is correct. But I would adjust it a bit to read:

> Most students are able to expertly manage their time while working
>   along their other responsibilities.

Comment: That doesn't flow, IMHO. "working along their other responsibilities" doesn't seem like a proper verb phrase.